# Teradata, splitting field into several rows Using STRTOK_SPLIT_TO_TABLE for <b> and <\b> Syntax error

Tags: teradata, strtok

I have this in one field called Content

```
<b>Value 1</b> <b>Value 2 </b> - <b>Value 3 </b>
```

I want to break each of the contents in each field into separate records, so if there is 5, I'd have 5 records, if it has 20 id have 20 records, etc.   I tried using this:

```
SELECT d.* FROM Audit as t (strtok_split_to_table(t.ID, t.CONTENT, '</b>')
   RETURNS (outkey integer, tokennum integer, token varchar(20)character set unicode) ) as d order by 1,2;
```

But it errors out to  Syntax error, expected something like ';' between the word 't' and '('. Is there a better way to do this without using strtok_split_to_table  I'm a newbie so dont go too hard on me, :)

Contents of the cell look like this                             ```

````
<b>Case Owner</b></b> <b>Old Value : </b> - <b>New Value : </b>joe.mercer <br/>  <BR>NoteID: 123456</BR><BR>Action: Add</BR><BR>NoteType: Big Note</BR>                        <BR>NoteID: 123456</BR><BR>Action: Update</BR><BR>NoteType: Big Note</BR>               
<b>Notes</b> <b>Old Value : </b> - <b>New Value : </b>THIS IS AN BIG DEAL~SEE DEAL # A1223456.  <br/> <b>Decision Date</b> <b>Old Value : </b> - <b>New Value : </b>08-05-2021 09:05 <br/> <b>Initial Review Completed Date</b> <b> ``` 
``` <b>Sub Category</b> <b>Old Value : </b>Radio Service(E101) - <b>
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is messed up (you need a Derived Tab le or CTE) and STRTOK splits on characters, not strings (any of these characters will split, not the sequence `'</b>'`).

You need RegExp_split_to_table and another RegEx to clean the result:

```
with t as
 (
   select id, CONTENT
   from Audit
)
select id, TokenNum
  ,regexp_substr(Token, '.*<b>\K.*') -- trim everything up to '<b>'
FROM TABLE (RegExp_Split_To_Table(t.id, t.content, '<\/b>', 'i') -- split whenever '<\/b>' occurs
     RETURNS ( id INT,
               TokenNum INT,
               Token VARCHAR(100) CHARACTER SET Unicode)
             ) AS dt
```

Edit:

Regarding the 9134 error: Try increasing the length of the result TOKEN. And if your input is a VarChar(35000) it can't be UNICODE -> change to LATIN, too.

Comment: What is the declared data type of MHK_CONTENT and what is the length of the actual largest input? And also, how large is your largest "value" / Token to be returned?

Comment: MHK_CONTENT: VarChar(35000)

Comment: Heres whats in the one cell <b>Procedure/HCPS Code : </b> 70553 <br/>
 <b>Procedure/HCPS description : </b> Magnetic resonance (eg, proton) imaging, brain (including brain stem); without contrast material, followed by contrast material(s) and further sequences <br/>
<b>PA Status</b> Prior Authorization Required <br/> 
<b>Frequency : </b> As Necessary <br/> 
<b>Auth Units : </b> Units <br/> 
<b>Short Code Description : </b> MRI of the brain <br/> 
 I want I want to extract everything from <b> to <br/>end result s/b  "User Updated or Added Procedure/HCPS Code : 70553" etc. etc.

Comment: ~~~Thank you this is what worked for me now i got to play around with it some, like if theres an old value then its an update <b>Expected Discharge Date</b> <b>Old Value : </b>08-18-2021 00:00 - <b>New Value : </b>08-24-2021 00:00 <br/> Distinguishing if its a new value or if its a changed value.   Like this example is there's no old value so its new.<b>Review Number/Revision</b> <b>Old Value : </b> - <b>New Value : </b>H4500894/1 <br/>, so final value says "Value added for Expected Discharge Date" vs "Review Number added".  What do I do with the other cells it creates: ex: 31183026 eg, prot

Comment: These old/new values are outside of the <b> </b> pairs and will not be captured correctly. `'<\/b>|<b>'` will create additional rows (no more regexp_substr needed) and based on the TokenNum you can apply LAG/LEAD to get the matching values

Comment: so if i have this with others like this. What can I do to split them out into individual rows? ~~~<b>Discharge Date</b> <b>Old Value : </b> - <b>New Value : </b>08-10-2021 13:54 <br/> <b>Expected Discharge Date</b> <b>Old Value : </b>08-12-2021 00:00 - <b>New Value : </b>08-10-2021 00:00 <br/>

Comment: @dnoeth can you show me how to do the '<\/b>|<b>' will create additional rows, which is my expectation, LAG/LEAD to get the matching values. how can i complete this, where can i read up on this? what do you read or study to be smart like you for teradata sql?

Comment: @dnoeth here's what i am using            with t as
 (
   select MHKAUDITLOGINTERNALID as id, Cast(MHK_CONTENT as CLOB)as MHK_CONTENT
   from vcoreMEDHOK_MHK_Audit
   Where cast(AUDITDATETIME as Date) >= '2021/08/15')
select ID, 
           regexp_substr(Token, '.*<b>*\K.*') -- trim everything up to '<b>'
FROM TABLE (RegExp_Split_To_Table(t.id, t.MHK_CONTENT,'<\/b>', 'i')  -- split whenever '<\/b>' occurs
     RETURNS ( id BIGINT,
               TokenNum INT,
               Token VARCHAR(35000) CHARACTER SET LATIN)) AS dt   [Teradata Database] Error  [9134] Output exceeds buffer

Comment: [Teradata Database] Error  [9134] Output exceeds buffer,  
 im getting this using the above.   i used 1 record and this is what i got  
31181086 Discharge Date
31181086 Old Value : 
31181086 New Value :                                                                                                                                                                                                         31181086 Discharge Date  Old Value : New Value :    08-10-2021 13:54      
31181086 Expected Discharge Date Old Value :  08-12-2021 00:00 -New Value : 08-10-2021 00:00

Comment: Now I see, there are two different tags, `<br/>` and `<b>`/`<|b>`. You probably want `'<BR/> *'` for splitting and then maybe `regexp_replace(Token, '<b>|<\/b>')` to remove the tags. Simply ask a new question for more details, comments are hard to read.

Comment: Regarding being smart: it's just 35+ years of SQL and almost 25 years of Teradata :-)